# APC, disk hits, and requires/includes

Tags: php, apc

Pretty simple question, but I can't actually tell for sure. How does PHP behave with requires/includes of files that have been already cached by APC? My understanding is that this cache primarily saves PHP of compiling a file that has been already cached, but it's not clear to me whether it also saves the disk hit necessary to find/fetch the file aswell; so, does it? Or will PHP hit the disk, even if the opcode has been already cached, the only difference being that it doesn't do the compilation process again?

I would like to think requires/includes magically know a file is cached and thus fetch it directly from memory thanks to APC, but I just realized I have no reason to assume this is case, hence why I ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APC overrides the function zend_compile_file in the Zend Engine, which among other things is responsible locating and opening the actual files; thanks to this it is able to "hijack" disk hits before they happen if the file is already cached.

Therefore, yes, files are served from memory if cached.

Sources: [APC Technotes](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/apc/branches/APC_4_0/TECHNOTES.txt?view=markup) and the Zend Engine source code, specifically [zend_language_scanner.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_scanner.c)

Answer (score 4):

I think your questions on this topic is explained in the APC manual, but it is sort of hidden. you must read the [configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php) part to find it. Especially check out the [apc.stat](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat) configuration option which states this:

> ... This defaults to on, forcing APC to stat (check) the script on
>   each request to determine if it has been modified. If it has been
>   modified it will recompile and cache the new version. If this setting
>   is off, APC will not check
>   ...
>   For included/required files this option applies as well, but note that
>   for relative path includes (any path that doesn't start with / on
>   Unix) APC has to check in order to uniquely identify the file. If you
>   use absolute path includes APC can skip the stat and use that absolute
>   path as the unique identifier for the file.

So it looks like APC is caching required/included files in much the same way as the original script, **if you include/require by the absolute path to the file**. If you are using a relative path (which many do) it will require a disk hit to find out the full file name.

Comment: This setting from what I can read tells APC whether or not to look for changes in the file to rebuild the opcode cache, but the opcode cache is one thing, and the initial file look up made by include/require is another; this doesn't necesarily have to be related and it doesn't state whether it is. That is, perhaps APC will not check for changes on disk if apc.stat is set to off, but will requires/includes skip the file look up process and fetch it from memory? It's still unclear to me.

Comment: @Mahn: it will fetch them from memory as long as they are cached

Answer (score 1):

Actually, APC **does** OPEN syscalls for the *once variants (include_once, require_once). 
You can check this easily using strace.

That is because the code for the *once is slighty different, calling zend_stream_open
before calling compile_filename (which is overwritten by apc):

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_execute.h

There is an open issue in the bug tracker too:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59372